# Ubuntu 13.10 amd64 Live-USB Not saving

Tags: 13.10, live-usb, reboot, persistence, live-environment

So this week I have been messing around with my USB drive. I decided to make myself an Ubuntu Live-USB drive (as I have done in the past). So I downloaded unetbootin and Ubuntu 13.10 amd64 and set the persistence for 8 Gigs. It was too big, so I changed it to 3. It worked that time, so I rebooted. That's where it first went wrong. So I then went to download YUMI (Your Universal Multiboot Installer, look it up on Google). I set the persistence to 3 gigs. I rebooted. it worked perfectly!.... Until the end. I reboot the Ubuntu live-installation only to find all my stuff was gone. What is wrong?